# CentOS 6.7 hangs after progress bar

Tags: centos, gui

does someone has been in this problem with CentOS 6.7 ?
X does not finish to complete.. missing icons and menu.

[image]

[image]

**What I already did:**

1) Install nvidia drivers

2) Uninstall nvidia drivers
      yum remove kmod-nvidia*
      yum remove xorg-x11-drv-nvidia*

3) Install elrepo kmod-nvidia from elrepo.org / tiki / kmod-nvidia

4) Uninstall el repo kmod-nvidia drivers

5) rename xorg.conf to xorg.conf.old (it works just once)

**What the log shows:**

> [root@seig log]# cat Xorg.5.log
>   [    36.423] X.Org X Server 1.15.0
>    Release Date: 2013-12-27
>   [    36.423] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
>   [    36.423] Build Operating System: c6b8 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 
>   [    36.423] Current Operating System: Linux seig 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 13 22:55:16 UTC 2015 x86_64
>   [    36.423] Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_seig-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_seig/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_seig/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=la-latin1 rhgb quiet crashkernel=131M@0M nouveau.modeset=0 rdblacklist=nouveau
>   [    36.424] Build Date: 23 July 2015  05:32:11PM
>   [    36.424] Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.15.0-36.el6.centos 
>   [    36.424] Current version of pixman: 0.32.4
>   [    36.424]   Before reporting problems, check http:// wiki. centos. org/ Documentation
>       to make sure that you have the latest version.
>   [    36.424] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
>       (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
>       (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
>   [    36.424] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.5.log", Time: Thu Sep 17 23:34:39 2015
>   [    36.424] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
>   [    36.424] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
>   [    36.424] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
>   [    36.424] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
>   [    36.424] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
>   [    36.425] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
>   [    36.425] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
>   [    36.425] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
>   [    36.425] (==) Automatically adding devices
>   [    36.425] (==) Automatically enabling devices
>   [    36.425] (==) Not automatically adding GPU devices
>   [    36.425] (**) FontPath set to:
>       /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1,
>       catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d,
>       built-ins
>   [    36.425] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/nvidia,/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
>   [    36.425] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
>   [    36.425] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
>   [    36.425] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
>   [    36.425] (II) Loader magic: 0x823020
>   [    36.425] (II) Module ABI versions:
>   [    36.425]   X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
>   [    36.425]   X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
>   [    36.425]   X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
>   [    36.425]   X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
>   [    36.434] (--) PCI:*(0:9:0:0) 102b:0534:1028:0602 rev 1, Mem @ 0x90000000/16777216, 0x91800000/16384, 0x91000000/8388608, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension Present
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
>   [    36.434] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
>   [    36.434] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
>   [    36.435] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/nvidia/libglx.so
>   [    36.465] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
>   [    36.465]   compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    36.465]   Module class: X.Org Server Extension
>   [    36.465] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  352.41  Fri Aug 21 22:40:16 PDT 2015
>   [    36.465] Loading extension GLX
>   [    36.465] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
>   [    36.466] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
>   [    36.467] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
>   [    36.467]   compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    36.467]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
>   [    36.467] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  352.41  Fri Aug 21 22:14:01 PDT 2015
>   [    36.467] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
>   [    36.467] (++) using VT number 1
>
> [    36.473] (EE) No devices detected.
>   [    36.473] (EE) 
>   Fatal server error:
>   [    36.473] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
>   [    36.473] (EE) 
>   Please consult the CentOS support 
>        at wiki.centos.org/Documentation
>    for help. 
>   [    36.473] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.5.log" for additional information.
>   [    36.473] (EE)

Comment: I would suggest to edit while booting up to take out "quiet splash" and then let the system boot up. While the xorg does say something about 'no screens found' you will find more clues if you boot up without the splash/plymouth.

Comment: Remove `rhgb` and add `verbose` in addition to above.

Comment: @shirish Yesterday I make the X desktop appear but as soon as I close my session from my laptop de Window in the server backs to text mode (console). I also follow this procedure without luck:

Generate and customize xorg.conf [link] (https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2013-January/131660.html

This command:
lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'

Returns this card:
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2

Thank you guys, I appreciate any feedback

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I remove the rhgb line and also add verbose.. unfortunately time goes out and I had to backup and reinstall the O.S. again.
Thanks for your time guys!!